# use GET method in node js request?

Tags: node.js

i want to pass data with GET method in node js , my response is ok but in php file $_GET is empty. what is wrong?

```
var querystring = require('querystring');
var req = require('request');
var form = {
    number: 'test',
    msg: 'test',
};

var formData = querystring.stringify(form);
var contentLength = formData.length;

req({

    headers: {
      'Content-Length': contentLength,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    uri: 'http://localhost:8080/sms/index.php',
    body: formData,
    method: 'GET'

  }, function (err, res, body) {
        console.log('res is',res);
        console.log('err',err);
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HTTP GET request cannot have a request body. `$_GET` parses parameters from the query string. The headers `Content-Length`and `Content-Type` do not make sense for a GET request as they apply to the body of the request, which `GET` cannot have. You need to use the `qs` option instead of `body`.

```
req({
    uri: 'http://localhost:8080/sms/index.php',
    qs: form,
    method: 'GET'
  }, function (err, res, body) {
        //
  });
```